# Validating whether PDF file Uploaded as part of Geoprocessing Service of ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I'm developing a Python Script that will be a Geoprocessing Service in ArcGIS Server.

The Script has a Button for Users to OPTIONALLY Upload a PDF.
If the PDF is Uploaded it gets inserted into the pack.
If no Upload I want the Code to Skip appending Page.

How would I perform the Check and pass if no Upload?

Comment: Would you be able to include a code snippet from your code so far, that works up to the point where you are stuck, please?  The answer *seems* easy - just use `arcpy.Exists()` to test whether the PDF has been uploaded if you know its name, if it does then append it, if not then `pass`.  If you just want to test whether any PDF file has been uploaded then use `arcpy.ListFiles()` to look for `*.pdf` files in the folder you have them uploaded to.